# Are the new and delete operators thread-safe in pthreads-w32 for visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, thread-safety, pthreads

Are the new and delete operators thread-safe in pthreads-w32 for visual c++?

What things should I assume will always be thread-safe in pthreads-w32?

Answer (score 1):

I think the C++ standard doesn't say anything about thread-safety. Threads are simply not (yet) part of the concept. But I'm sure each compiler vendor has his/her own answer to that question. Check your compiler's documentation. I'd be surprized if the built-in new/delete operators were *not* thread-safe.

Comment: I was a bit irritated, pthreads is a C lib and I thought the question was regarding some new/delete implementation in pthreads!!! The default new/delete are thread safe (global heap lock is used, which costs some performance drop in single threaded apps)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all system functions are thread safe, if you build your project with 'Multi-threaded' run-time libraries.